# location of sofia profile

Tags: freeswitch

I am not able to connect to freeswitch server because it is not configured correctly. I get an error...

```
call failed: forbidden
```

The freeswitch log says...

```
2013-01-14 02:33:33.014079 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2491 Can't find user [mike@10.195.201.14]
You must define a domain called '10.195.201.14' in your directory and add a user with the id="mike" attribute
and you must configure your device to use the proper domain in it's authentication credentials.
2013-01-14 02:33:33.014079 [NOTICE] sofia.c:1717 Hangup sofia/internal/mike@ec.amazonaws.com [CS_NEW] [CALL_REJECTED]
2013-01-14 02:33:33.014079 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1517 Session 3 (sofia/internal/mike@ec.amazonaws.com) Ended
2013-01-14 02:33:33.014079 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1521 Close Channel sofia/internal/mike@ec2amazonaws.com [CS_DESTROY]
```

When I searched, I got this link...

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia#Forcing_SIP_profile_to_use_a_static_IP_address

The default FreeSWITCH configuration will automatically determine the IP address of your local network interface. If you want to manually set the IP (for example, if you have multiple network interfaces on a single machine), you can set the following parameters in the Sofia profile:

```
<param name="rtp-ip" value="192.168.1.3"/>
```

Where exactly is this sofia profile file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/autoload_configs/sofia.conf.xml
```

I was able to connect to this server after adding the IP address to this file.

show channels and freeswitch client (/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli) are the 2 important points to remember. The core.db file is sql-lite file found in /usr/local/freeswitch/db/ seems to have tables like calls, complete, intefaces etc.